# Handle auto retrieve for react-native firebase phone auth on android

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to figure out how exactly to deal with the android auto retrieve for the firebase phone auth on react-native,

I'm following this docs :

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth#verifyPhoneNumber

when I log in with an Android device the .on() listener triggers both events: 
CODE_SENT and then AUTO_VERIFIED,

when it does reach the AUTO_VERIFIED the phoneSnapshot code and verificationID are set to null 
so I can't use the :

`const cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code)` in order to sign the user in.

what Am I missing here?

Comment: In `phoneSnapshot`, please check `state` and `error` if they are exists. You may not config the SHA-1.

Comment: I have the SHA-1 configured properly. state is "verified"

Comment: Please make sure you use correct SHA-1. There are multiple `debug.keystore`. Default one in `~/.android/debug.keystore` (Mac users) and `<your-project>/android/app/debug.keystore`. Check your `app>build.gradle>signingConfigs` to see which one you are using.